# Tag [try-except] should be a synonym of [try-catch]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, stack-overflow, retag-request, synonym-request

Python uses the keyword `except` for handling exceptions, where most other languages use `catch`. The tag [try-except](/questions/tagged/try-except) (46 questions) should be synonymized to [try-catch](/questions/tagged/try-catch), since it's exactly the same concept, and you can just add [python](/questions/tagged/python) to the search if you want to limit it to Python.

Comment: No, I don't think so.  It's not called `try-catch` in Python, it's called `try-except,` and the Pythonistas will attack you with a giant snake.

Comment: Looks like it also applies to [Delphi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19588272/cant-catch-access-violation), and there's a variant for [c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6600507/c-try-except-statement) I guess?

Answer (score 2):

I updated the tag wiki for Try/Except, to clarify its meaning.